# Using GPLv2 licensed library in engineer's thesis

Tags: licensing, license-notice, gpl-2

I wanted to base my engineer's thesis on Truffle framework (https://github.com/oracle/graal/tree/master/truffle) and GraalVM (https://github.com/oracle/graal). Truffle is licensed under **GPL 2 with Classpath exception**, Graal compiler and GraalVM is under **GPL 2**. What is more when downloading GraalVM from Oracle's website I am asked to accept OTN agreement (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/early-adopter-license-2299792.html).

Can I freely use this software in my thesis? Should I disclose information about the license in my thesis?

Comment: The fact that it is for a thesis is not important for the GPL, as long as you follow the GPL's requirements.

Comment: How would the software be involved in your thesis?

Comment: I want to develop language using Truffle framework and GraalVM. My thesis will include source code of interpreter, as well as paper work.

Comment: What you actually want to do is ask your supervisor if it is OK. Even if the GPL says it is OK, if your supervisor says it is not, then you fail your thesis.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My supervisor is OK with using these tools. But I am not sure if GPL allows such usage.

Comment: [Fair use](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)?

Comment: @KamilSobolewski If you distribute the source with your thesis, license any derivative works as GPL too, and include or refer to the GPL license notice, most likely you are complying already with the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You must abide by the GPL. This means that anybody who gets the code is entitled to full source. And you certainly have to disclose this fact. This all depends on if your work is a derivative, of course. Would neen more details to answer.

That in itself doesn't make your work any less valuable/less thesis-worthy.

Comment: I want to develop language using Truffle framework. GraalVM will serve as a runtime. My thesis will include source code of the interpreter, as well as paper work.